# jQuery Drag and Drop using class selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This must be a simple one for expert. I am new to JS/jQuery. I have got a script to drag and copy and I modified it according to my requirements. It is implemented with "id" selectors. I want to implement the same using "class" selectors.

Here is the [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2no0f7db/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#arsenal').on("dragstart", ( function (e) {
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text", e.target.id);
}));

$('#leftbox').on("dragenter", ( function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}));

$('#leftbox').on("dragover", ( function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}));

$('#leftbox').on("drop", ( function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).empty();
    var data=e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
    nodeCopy.id = "newId";
    e.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
}));

});
```

Explanation:
I have a requirement where I need to implement this for a set of images which are dynamically added(with JS). So I cannot use Id of the target images. I need to use class. I tried but couldn't get it working.
Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's a basic JSFiddle of what you're doing using classes.](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/2no0f7db/4/)

It's pretty much a matter of changing your selctor:

```
$('.draggableImg').on("dragstart", ( function (e) {
    ...
});
```

There's also a minor problem -- if you have dragged an image to the `leftbox`, and then drag the image in `leftbox` to `leftbox`... you'll get an error. (You might just need to `removeClass` after copying the image to `leftbox`).

Alterantively, if you're saying that your elements *won't have ID's...* then you'll need to pass around the actual source of the image, rather than the element ID. Here's an [updated fiddle which does that](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/2no0f7db/19/).

And [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/2no0f7db/20/) one where you always append to the box, rather than to the target (which may be the img which has just been cleared)!

Comment: You used id for the individual images(id=chelsea and id=arsenal). My concern is that I cant add the id to the images. Its a set of images which are added dynamically(image upload and the images can be deleted and new images can be added).

Comment: thanks. but it seems there is a minor problem. When you drag the image second time(or fourth time) it will not be copied. I will try to fix it.

Comment: If you dont have the ID´s when the user uploads an image, maybe you can add an id by yourself. Like taking the timestamp of the upload `var date = new Date().getTime();` and add an word before it, because only number are no valid html-ids i think.

Comment: Yes, I noticed this in your original code. It's because you're appending to `$(target.el)`  - which is the image (which is cleared). If you just append to `$(this)`, it'll be fine. I've updated my answer with another Fiddle.

Comment: @DerVampyr Element ID's can start with a number, it's valid according to the HTML5 spec. But it makes applying CSS a bit tricky - `#100 { color:#000 }` wont work, whereas `[id='100'] { color:#000; }` will.

Answer (score 2):

Class selector (".class") selects all elements with the given class. An element can have multiple classes; only one of them must match.

So simply replace ids with clas selectors, like this:

```
$('.class').on("dragstart", ( function (e) {
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text", e.target.id);
}));
```

Comment: well, have you put the right class names that correspond with the class names of the elements you wish to drag?

Comment: It doesnt work, because the `var data=e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Text");` in the drop event is undefined if u use the code with `e.target.class`

Comment: He updated his code. Should work exaclty like the code from `Dave Salomon`

Answer (score 2):

Use something like '.js-drag-item' and '.js-drop-target' to replace your div id's. I like to add 'js-' so I remember it is a class name that has Javascript associated with it rather than CSS.

e.g.

JS

```
$('.js-drag-item').on("dragstart", ( function (e) {
   e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text", e.target.id);
}));
```

HTML

```
<section class="js-drag-item">
    ....
</section>
<section class="js-drag-item">
    ....
</section>
etc
```

You can have as many drag items or drop items as you want and the JS will be applied to all of them